# Create graphic from array

Tags: python-3.x

the following code does not work and I can not fix it, someone could help me? The error that comes out is as follows. What this should do is draw in a window all the points of the array, with time being the X and the value being Y, but when passing it through a loop it fails.

```
    pt = Point(array2[x], 100)
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Code

```
import numpy as np
from graphics import *

arrayX = []
arrayY = []

win = GraphWin(width = 600, height = 300) # create a window


arrayX = np.loadtxt("time.txt")
arrayY = np.loadtxt("value.txt")

array2 = arrayX.astype(int)
print(type(array2[2]))

for x in arrayX:
    pt = Point(x, arrayY[x])
    pt.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
```

time.txt

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
7
100
22
```

value.txt

```
100
100
50
20
34
67
23
89
43
```

Comment: You can just use `pt = Point(x, 100)` since you are iterating over each element.

Comment: But x will have values like 1,2,3,4.... in time.txt there are values like 100, i cant use directly x

Comment: no it wont, `for x in arrayX:` will iterate over each element in your `arrayX` i.e. `1
1
1
1
1
1
7
100
22`

Comment: Oh yes, it works, but now how can i do for y? I will edit the example in the code

Comment: The real question is, what do YOU want to do with y?